# Update table property from a value in a same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an Employee Data table with following properties

```
Id Emp_name Supervisor_Name Supervisor_id
1   A           B
2   B           
3   C           B
```

I want to update the Supervisor_Id column with Id value equal to Supervisor_Name. The output will be as follows.

```
Id Emp_name Supervisor_Name Supervisor_id
1   A           B               2
2   B           
3   C           B               2
```

What is the optimum SQL query to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self join would do the job

```
update e1
set e1.Supervisor_id=e.id
from Employee e1
join Employee e
on e1.Supervisor_Name =e.Emp_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UPDATE` with `INNER JOIN` syntax:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Supervisor_id = t2.Id
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.Supervisor_Name = t2.Emp_name
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9219d/1)